# Name ' ' ignored for PRIMARY KEY [MySql MariaDB 10.4.11]

Tags: mysql, terminal, mariadb, mariadb-10.4

I have a problem with those lines on my MAC, on mariaDB 10.4.11 version.

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS Employe_Programmeurs;
CREATE DATABASE Employe_Programmeurs;
USE Employe_Programmeurs;

CREATE TABLE Employe(
    noEmp      INT(5),
    nom        VARCHAR(10),
    prenom     VARCHAR(10),
    CONSTRAINT pk_Employe_noEmp PRIMARY KEY (noEmp) 
);
```

It tells me that :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QhgX.png]

And when I enter those lines on Windows, it works without warning and I can see them in the SHOW CREATE TABLE.
On Mac, it doesn't show me the CONSTRAINT of this Primary key on SHOW CREATE TABLE.

I updated, downgraded, but still no solution.

Comment: PK constraint always have a name `PRIMARY`. Without exclusions, alternatives and aliases. [CREATE TABLE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-table/#index-definitions): *For PRIMARY KEY indexes, you can specify a name for the index, but it is silently ignored, and the name of the index is always PRIMARY.*

Comment: @Akina What do you mean by "have a name PRIMARY" ?

Comment: @CloudData All indexes and constraints have a name. Most of them allow you to specify the name when you're creating them, but the primary key is always named `PRIMARY`. You're trying to give it the name `pk_Employe_noEmp`, but it can only have one name.

Comment: Are you running the same version of MariaDB on both Windows and Mac? Maybe this restriction has changed between versions.

Comment: Please read the article by the link. It's documentation words, I only reproduce them.

Comment: @Akina Thanks for your help ! I do have 2 different versions on Mac and Windows, and as Barmar said, the restriction has changed between versions. From 10.4.6 to 10.4.11 somewhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @Akina mentioned, for PRIMARY KEY indexes, you can specify a name for the index, but it will be silently ignored, its name will always be PRIMARY.

And my problem was that I had 2 different versions (10.4.6) on windows and (10.4.11) on mac.

So basically, the 10.4.6 version of MariaDB didn’t show any warnings and they changed that in 10.4.11, by putting this warning.